Share firebase firestores between apps flutter
I have a flutter app for android and ios using firestore and it is working fine.
I am now trying to implement another flutter app but now only web. It is meant to be kind of admin tool.
Through the firebase console I have added it to the same project as the previous.
When I now try to access the collections I get [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] Missing or insufficient permissions.
Am I missing something?

That error means your security rules are rejecting the query.  Please edit the question to show your rules and the query that was rejected.  We should be able to copy what you have and observe the same result.

Please edit your question and add the information Doug asked for, and please also respond using @.

I had to implement an authentication process. After that I could access the firestore database as signed in user.
